# How to query the result of a method in Ruby (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm struggling with a particular feature.

In my users model I have a method to work out their age based on the current date less their first order date.

I'd like to be able to find all users who are older than X days. I can find active users by querying a column called state for 'active' users. But I'm unsure how to query the result of the age method to find users older than X.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks and seasons greetings.

**Edit

In postgresql I would write;

```
WITH 
firstbill as (
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(user_id) as customer,
  DATE(MIN(billed_at)) as first_order
FROM orders
WHERE state = 'shipped'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1)

SELECT count*
FROM 
(SELECT *, (current_date - first_order) as age
FROM firstbill
JOIN users on users.id = customer) as t2
WHERE age >= 21
```

I have tried using User.find_by_sql["above query"] but that returns an array not activerecord relation which makes any further joins a little harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really query for the return value of a method. Because to do so, you need to load all users and then call that method on every user, like this `User.all.select(&:your_method?)`. That will be very slow if you have many users.

But for your particular example you can write something like this to let the database return the correct users (assuming you have a `first_order`column on your user):

```
User.where('first_order <= ?', 90.days.ago)
```

or

```
User.where('first_order <= ?', 1.month.ago)
```

I think the following startment should return the same users than your Postgresql example:

```
User.
  select('users.*, MIN(DATE(orders.billed_at)) AS first_order_on').
  joins('orders ON orders.user_id = users.id').     # just `(:orders)` with `has_many :order` on User 
  where('orders.state = ?', 'shipped').
  group('users.id').
  having('first_order_on <= ?', 21.days.ago.to_date)
```

Comment: which will give him a sql error, saying, that birthday column is undefined for users table. As per OP description, he wants to query based on method's results, not by db column.

Comment: The issue with the proposed answer is that it requires the first order to be a column. What I'm trying to get is that first_order value

Comment: @user2420484 : Can you please post how you calculate that value. Otherwise I can only guess what might work for you...

Comment: Sure, this is what i'd use in postgresql to query it.

WITH 
 firstbill as (
 SELECT 
   DISTINCT(user_id) as customer,
   DATE(MIN(billed_at)) as first_shipment
 FROM orders
 WHERE state = 'shipped'
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1)

SELECT count*
FROM 
 (SELECT *, (current_date - first_shipment) as age
 FROM firstbill
 JOIN users on users.id = customer) as t2
WHERE age >= 21

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
scope :acquired, User.joins(:orders).where("orders.state = ?", "shipped")
scope :older_than_age, ->(age) {
acquired.group("users.id").having("(current_date - date(min(orders.shipped_at))) >= ?", age)
}
```